# Wheel Spacer Question - Stuck Nuts

Tags: wheels, lug-nut

I bought a car that had wheel spacers fitted, they are for cosmetic reasons only but I prefer the car to be standard so today took the wheel off and proceeded to remove the spacers nuts.

They do not move at all, not even slightly, I have tried release spray and they still do not move, I have put so much force into it I have cracked 2 sockets, one of which was an impact socket!

So now I am stuck, I can leave the spacers on the car but I am concerned about the release spray I have put on there, in time will the nuts come undone by themselves? Is there anything I can use to "flush" the release spray?

Or do I still try and undo the nuts, I don't even know what socket to use, 20mm 6 sided is too small but 21mm 6 sided feels a little loose, can also see the nuts themselves starting to round.

Any advice please, under the circumstances I can leave the nuts on there but I am concerned about that release spray being on there.

Bit out of my depth so all help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you provided images of what you're talking about as well as information about the car (year/make/model/engine/transmission), we might be able to help you better.

Comment: Sounds like the actual size is ¹³∕₁₆" (0.8125 in) and neither 20mm (0.787402 in) nor 21mm (0.826772 in).

Comment: I'd find someone that knows something about the mystery vehicle and ask if the spacers are installed with a left hand thread.

Comment: Is it possible that these were installed using "red" threadlocker?  If so, you may want to try heating them, to about 500F as I recall, and see if that allows them to come out.

Comment: Use a quality socket - I have broken or shattered several but never a Snap-On socket and I have an impact socket by Snap-On in my car for that reason.

Comment: Hi, Sorry bit new to this forum, its a 2006 Ford Focus ST - UK

Comment: The car is fitted with H&R Wheel Spacers, not sure how you link pictures?

Comment: Jeeped - You could be right, I don't have a 6 sided 18/16" but it seemed to fit well with the standard socket I have but after breaking 2 I haven't actually tried it to undo anything. The threads are normal right handed. The problem I have is standard sockets won't fit only thin walled ones :/

Comment: I don't think I have the rep to link pictures yet so not sure if this will work, in the picture the spacer is placed on the hub and secured through the highlighted holes with the nuts provided, its those nuts I cannot get off - https://imgur.com/gjbQUpd

Comment: What will happen to the release spray, will it just disipate over time? I read that its unlikely to penetrate the threads if you can't even get the nut to turn, is that correct? And sorry for all the comments, I can't seem to work out how you start a new paragraph